# Deny external access to folder

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, upload

is there a way to deny outside access to my upload directory ?! I don't want users to access my upload directory : www.example.com/uploads

i used .htaccess in the root of my upload folder however all the links were broken

in my .htaccess :

```
deny from all
```

any solution ?

Comment: >>I don't want users to access my upload directory<< >>however all the links were broken<< that sounds your htaccess work ;)

Comment: I think I've answered your question, but if not you need to provide a bit more clarification. What kind of access do you wish to block, and which kind of access do you wish to allow? Access to the directory must be allowed if users are to download files.

Comment: Exactly ! my htaccess works perfectly, but he is doing the wrong job :) 
as I said, I don't want external access to my folder : www.example.com/uploads must show the 'denied access' message ( and this is the case here ) but on other way I don't want to broke my links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to disable directory listing, simply place 'Options -Indexes' in your htaccess.

You've applied a 'deny from all', which essentially stops ANYONE from accessing files in the directory to which it applies.

Also make sure that 'AllowOverride All' is specified in the vhost definition, otherwise you are unable to override settings via the htaccess file. That is my understanding anyway.

If you wish to disable access to the upload directory, and control which files in specific users can access, I'd recommend going through a script written in a language such as PHP. A user requests a file from the script, the script looks to see if they're allowed to view the file. IF they are, they file is displayed. IF they aren't then it is not.

References

- http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml
- http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/apache-allowoverride-all

Comment: thanks dude ! 
I'm already using a script in my controller to see if the user is allowed to view the file or not, but, the user must go through the front controller to go through the verification, which is not the case if  he access directly to my folder.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. You could actually pipe the file contents through the controller, instead of serving it up directly using Apache. This would mean you could completely deny access to the uploads directory, and eliminate the risk of an uploaded file link being shared to people who should not have access to it.

Comment: I was thinking about piping contents throught the controller and the only idea I had is to use X-SendFile and the readFile method .. I'm I on the right track ?!

Comment: You should be able to simply read the contents of the file, and output it to the client, using a 'Content-Disposition' header of 'Attachment', and the correct 'Content-Type' header for the file type. A Disposition of Attachment will mean the file is always downloaded, instead of displayed in the browser.